# Getting segmentation fault in import gi.repository in Python PyGobject?

Tags: python-3.x, segmentation-fault, gstreamer, pygobject

I have installed gstreamer from source using cerbero with the help of this link (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-cerbero.html?gi-language=c)

All the packages are installed in the cerbero subdirectory (cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64) and the gstreamer version is updated to 1.18. I have installed on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

As gstreamer version 1.14 is available with the ubuntu 18.04 distribution, to make the system pick the latest version of gstreamer, the cerbero shell needs to be activated on the terminal using the command.

```
$ cerbero shell
```

After this the terminal console is like

```
[cerbero-linux-x86_64] name@sample-Latitude-5400:~/cerbero/
```

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 --version
gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.18.4
GStreamer 1.18.4 (GIT)
```

I want to run a python script that imports gi (Gobject introspection) to access the gstreamer library. But when I import gi.repository package, it give the segmentation fault.

GI_TYPELIB_PATH environment variable is also set.

```
$ echo $GI_TYPELIB_PATH
cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/lib/girepository-1.0
```

The starting lines of code.

```
import gi                             # Works fine
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')      # Works fine
from gi.repository import Gst         # Segmentation Fault
```

Following is the traceback when I run the python script (python 3.6)

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f2a01ba8740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_option.py", line 47 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023 in _handle_fromlist
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 37 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994 in _gcd_import
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126 in import_module
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 125 in load_overrides
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 146 in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626 in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994 in _gcd_import
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126 in import_module
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 145 in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626 in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994 in _gcd_import
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126 in import_module
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 145 in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626 in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023 in _handle_fromlist
  File "webrtc_sendrecv_wowza16.py", line 15 in <module>
Segmentation fault
```

Can anyone suggest what could be the possible reason ?